# Total of each element in dictionary by python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have data file like this:

```
{'one', 'four', 'two', 'eight'}
{'two', 'three', 'seven', 'eight'}
```

I want to get total of element and count each element. The result like this:

```
total of element: 8
one: 1, two: 2, eight: 2, seven: 1, three: 1, four: 1
```

Here is my code:

```
with open("data.json") as f:
     for line in f:
         result = json.loads(line)
         if 'text' in result.keys():
             response = result['text'] 
             words = response.encode("utf-8").split()
        list={}
        for word in words:
```

After this, I don't know how to get total of element and count each element. 
could you help me?

Comment: Are you creating a set or a list?

Comment: Does your txt data file really look like that?

Comment: No, I just want to know how many element and count the each element.

Comment: Try to split your problem: first, read the file and put its content in a Python structure (e.g. a list of dictionaries); then process the structure and get the result.

Comment: Do not use 'list' as a variable: it would override the default 'list' function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections

counter = collections.Counter()

with open("data.json") as f:
    for line in f:
        result = json.loads(line)
        if 'text' in result.keys():
            response = result['text']
            words = response.encode("utf-8").split()
            counter.update(words)
print(counter)
```

Comment: I've added a print statement to assist with debugging. Please post the last line printed before the `ValueError`.

Comment: File "test.py", line 22, in main
    counter.update(ast.literal_eval(word))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 60, in _convert
    return list(map(_convert, node.elts))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
this is error part before the valueerror

Comment: Your edit changes the question considerably. You have JSON data, so you do not need to use `ast.literal_eval`. Using a `collections.Counter` is probably all you need. But to show you exactly how to use it you have to show us what your data looks like **exactly**. If your data is private, just change the words without changing the format.

Comment: First of all. sorry for my mistake!! I think that the result will be the same as txt file. Json file is dictionary type of data. it has a 'text'keys, so I need only 'text'keys. The words type is list and it same as {'one', 'four', 'two', 'eight'} {'two', 'three', 'seven', 'eight'} of my initial part in my post . I really appreciate your help!